# Email Line Height Html

Tags: android, css, email, html-email

I am tearing my hair out on how to get things to display properly in email with signatures in Mobile devices.

I tried in HTML and Word.

I have tried making it in Word which had the best result, only that when reading it in Mobile version of Gmail and Outlook, for Android, that the line heights are way too big and tables are not displaying properly as seems theyre also getting this massive line heights in them even though they are blank.

I done some research and it says that Gmail seem to change your line heights? I havent been able to work out in how to fix it.

I have just ripped back the other parts and have the basic code here:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5ncxuk0/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        p {
            font-size: 8pt;
            line-height: 12pt!important;
            margin: 0;
        }

    </style>

</head>


<body>

<table width="320px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10.0pt 5.4pt 0pt 5.4pt; border-top: 5px solid #2E38A5; border-bottom: 5px solid #2E38A5; "><table width="320px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td height="10pt" colspan="4" align="right" style="" >Logo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><p style="line-height: 12pt; margin: 0">First Last</p>
              <p style="line-height: 12pt; margin: 0">Sales Director</p></td>
            <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10pt" colspan="3"></td>
            <td height="10pt"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="22" height="10pt"></td>
            <td width="18"></td>
              <td width="250" align="right"><p style="line-height: 8pt">+61 (0) 400 000 000 / +000 9000 0000</p>
                  <p style="line-height: 8pt">boris@email.com / www.website.com</p>
            </td>
            <td height="10pt"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10pt" colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10pt" colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10pt" colspan="4"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>




</body>
</html>
```

Also tried some methods other people had suggested to remove the links from phone numbers and email and have had no success with  tags etc. Is there a more recent trick?

Thanks. Hopefully I am specific enough.

Comment: I added `background: #ff0000;` to your `<p>` definition and checked the sample against Gmail, Outlook and the usual suspects and the line height is consistent across every email client.

Comment: I would suggest changing the line height from pts to px and test if you see any difference.